# Bug with Blender (the UI to be more specific) - weird stuttering and glitches

Tags: linux

I installed Blender in my PC (Ubuntu 16.04) and I've this weird stuttering and glitches on the GUI when I mouse over the cube from the startup project in sculpt mode. Also, when I maximize the window the stuttering and glitches become permanent.

The specs of my PC are:

- CPU: AMD FX-6300
- RAM: 8GB
- GPU: AMD R9 270X
- GPU-Driver: Open Source AMD - Mesa 13.1.0-devel

Blender was installed using: sudo apt-get install blender

Here's a short video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orUQFJKJlgQ&feature=youtu.be

https://gyazo.com/c9458a26f3445f6a7f4cf6b974325dc8

I'd like to know if it's a problem with my GPU, my drivers, this version of Blender in Linux, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I had graphical glitches as well with the mesa drivers. I fixed it by going to *File > User Preferences > System*, and under the *Window Draw Method* title select *Triple Buffer* and then press *Save User Settings*